# Using a Liferay data list for public-facing registration form?

Tags: forms, liferay

I am implementing a public-facing form that allows anyone on the Internet to register by filling a form containing very confidential information.

I am thinking about implementing this in Liferay using [Dynamic Data Lists](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/creating-data-lists-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-10-en).

**QUESTION:** Does this sounds like a sensible idea?

I am a bit afraid that Dynamic Data Lists are just a fancy gadget for collaborators to easily build web items, but not really intended for public-facing confidential forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to if the level of "confidentiality" is the key of your question: If DDL does the job, why not use it? You can have a form that faces the user, where they enter new data. The actual list of data doesn't need to be visible to the users.

On confidentiality, you probably want to closely administer your portal, e.g. be careful whom you give administrative access, consider using the audit plugins (EE only), update to the latest available version and use https (only) - which Liferay works quite well with.

You might want to be more specific as to what your fears are. If there's anything that would speak against this use, I'd personally rather consider it a bug than a feature that makes DDL unfit for actual use - and I'm not aware of such a bug currently.

Comment: For instance, by default all guests can see all records. That's not very confidential-oriented. I can try to fix the DDL to not show it, but maybe DDL is a bad choice for confidential information in the first place, and I should choose Web Forms instead? That's my worry.

Comment: Well, if you know that it's "by default" visible to guests, then the default might not be the setting that you need to use... (no pun intended). I'd worry only if there was no way to change the default. But as there are permissions that you can change for your DDL, I don't see any problems with this default.